# Can the NuGet 3.2 package cache location be changed

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a machine whose C:\ drive has limited space, but I have a large D:\ drive with plenty of space is it possible to change the location of the nuget package cache (I am using nuget 3.x)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Set an environment variable `NuGetCachePath` with the value of the path where you want the new package cache.

UPDATE: This answer is from 2016 and is no longer relevant for more modern versions of NuGet. As indicated below by @Mohsen the new Environment Variable to set is `NUGET_PACKAGES`

[image: Environment variable window]

Comment: Please add more (useful) information. Where could we set that variable?

Comment: @Marten it is a environment variable, you do it from the control panel. If you need help finding it [here is a tutorial on it for various versions of windows](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) just replace `PATH` in that tutorial with `NuGetCachePath`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore; see @Mohsen's answer below.

Answer (score 23):

You can override the default nuget package cache folder by an environment variable:

```
NUGET_PACKAGES
```

Reference: [Manage Global Packages and Cache Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)

Answer (score 12):

For nuget 3.0 and above I use the following script to redirect the packages folder to a folder in different drive for example for e:\nuget-cache as folder in another drive

```
pushd %USERPROFILE%\\

rmdir /Q /S .nuget

IF NOT EXIST e:\\nuget-cache mkdir e:\\nuget-cache

mklink /D .nuget e:\\nuget-cache
```

Comment: If the user profile is not on the same disk the `cd` command will fail. `pushd` will work.

Comment: None of the other answers here worked.  This is a good work around.

Comment: this work for me, use Command Prompt instead PowerShell

Comment: Needed to open a command prompt with administrator permissions for the mklink step